# How to rebuild OpenCV in Yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I would like to rebuild the OpenCV in the Yocto project

by this answer
[yocto: rebuild part of project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452798/yocto-rebuild-part-of-project)
it shall be
bitbake -c clean opencv
bitbake -c cleansstate opencv
bitbake -c cleanall opencv

But there is a error message happen:
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'opencv'

I have tried libopencv and doens't work too.
Does anyone know the correct name?
Thanks

Comment: do you have `meta-oe` in your `bblayers.conf`?

Comment: Yes, I can build the OpenCV successfully, but I just want to modify the OpenCV version.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the meta-oe layer provided by meta-openembedded. [This](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded) is the repo. Once that repo has been cloned to your project and added to your `bblayers.conf`, you should be able to build opencv.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can build the OpenCV itself by bitbake core-image-weston
 But I found that the version is wrong, I just want to modify the version and build again.

Comment: @RigelChen it sounds like you now have multiple different versions of opencv available for you to use. If that is the case, then you can specify the version you want to build with by setting `PREFERRED_VERSION:opencv = "1.2.3"` (or whatever version you want set) in your `local.conf`.

Comment: Thanks, that is much more faster than finding a new recipe.

Comment: To be clear, the recipe with that version must already exist. PREFERRED_VERSION is only used to choose between available recipes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is another layer to overwrite my desired OpenCV version. Remove the OpenCV recipe of that layer and build again and it works. But I'm not sure whether it is the correct way to deal with it.